# Adding tabbed content in D7

Tags: routes

What module should I use to make a tabbed block bringing views, custom content or forms?

For example I want to have a 
News | Twitter | Facebook | Feedback

Which would have a list of news (or a news block), twitter updates etc.
Feedback would have a form.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for something like the [Quicktabs](http://www.google.co.ke/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CEsQFjAA&url=http://drupal.org/project/quicktabs&ei=wNK8T_CNMMvrsgbD3JXjDQ&usg=AFQjCNEMQV9zQqbZGk7h1bl2-EszgiraSg) module. I have an implementation here: http://gamebah.com/gsqrd/node/24.

You  will make a block for each tab (Twitter, Facebook, Feedback, etc.) and then using Quicktabs (under Admin > Structure > Quicktabs) you can add the blocks to a new tab set. It is very self explanatory but if you need more help, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what I want.